# Do I need to provide type hints for methods overriding `@abstractmethod`s?

Tags: python, types, subclass, type-hinting, mypy

Given these two classes:

```
class MyClass(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def my_method(self, my_parameter: str):
        pass
    
class MySecondClass(MyClass):
    def my_method(self, my_parameter): 
        pass
```

Does `my_parameter` in `my_method` of `MySecondClass` have an inferred type of `Any` or `str` based on [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/)? I couldn't find an example detailing the above within the linked document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `Any`. You can try it out by running mypy:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class MyClass(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def my_method(self, my_parameter: str):
        pass
    
class MySecondClass(MyClass):
    def my_method(self, my_parameter):
        reveal_type(my_parameter)
        pass

MySecondClass().my_method(3)
```

[With](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.8&flags=check-untyped-defs&gist=51115d1f2c7387d06ca40db5879c9f49) or [without](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.8&gist=4bceb67faff3bc57b0fe74e3dae738f6) the [`--check-untyped-defs` flag](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_line.html#cmdoption-mypy-check-untyped-defs), this passes type checking, and [`reveal_type`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html?highlight=reveal_type#displaying-the-type-of-an-expression) reports `Any` as the type. (Without the flag, type checking is also skipped for the method body.)

---

Note that even with annotations, it is permitted for an overriding method to have a different signature than an overridden method, as long as the overriding method's signature is more permissive. For example, a method that takes an `Animal` can override a method that takes a `Dog`.